# ¿Por qué mis funciones no se ejecutan en el orden esperado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones

Hace poco que empece a desarrollar una aplicación web y me tope con el siguiente problema:

```
var template = {};
template = (function () {

var ROWS = -1;
var COLS = -1;

var _set = function (position) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: pathservicehost + '/posiciones/' + position,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            ROWS = data.TotalFila;
            COLS = data.TotalColumna;
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status) {
        }
    });

    if (PARAMETERS != null && ROWS > 0 && COLS > 0)
        _create(container);
};

var _create = function (container) {
    //Crea una tabla y lo coloca en 'container' usando las variables  globales ROWS y COLS
};

var _init = function (container, position) {
    _set(position);
    _create(container);
};

return {
    init: _init
}
})();
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando invoco a la función `init`, la función `_create` se ejecuta antes que `_set` y dado que los valores de las variables COLS y ROWS no se han inicializado aún, el programa me lanza una excepción.

Quisiera que por favor alguien me oriente acerca de como podría resolver dicho problema, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> El problema que tengo es que cuando invoco a la función init, la función _create se ejecuta antes que _set y dado que los valores de las variables COLS y ROWS no se han inicializado aún, el programa me lanza una excepción.

En realidad, `_set` se ejecuta primero, pero no olvides que JavaScript es monotarea y asincronico para todas las operaciones de Entrada/Salida, y dentro de `_set` estas haciendo una solicitud `ajax`.

Como una solicitud Ajax es una solicitud de entrada/salida no puedes llamar `_create` **consecutivamente** al método `_set`, debes hacerlo cuando termina la operación, es decir, en el "callback" que le pasas a jQuery... pues sera invocado cuando los datos sean recibidos.

En el código, invoca a `_create` dentro del callback de `success`: (mas comentarios en el código)

```
// a set le pasas el container pues lo necesitaras cunado invoques _create
var _set = function (container, position) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      // resto del codigo
      success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        ROWS = data.TotalFila;
        COLS = data.TotalColumna;

        // aquí invocas a _create, cuando ya tienes los datos.
        _create(container);
      },
      // resto del codigo
}
```

Luego cuando invocas `_set`

```
var _init = function (container, position) {
    _set(container, position);
};
```

Ojo! fíjate que en `_set`, agregue el orden de las variables para que tenga consistencia el código.

La parte que sigue la puedes borrar sin dudarlo, pues en ese punto tampoco llego la respuesta del servidor

```
if (PARAMETERS != null && ROWS > 0 && COLS > 0)
        _create(container);
```

Finalmente para simplificar las cosas puedes eliminar el método `_init` y renombrar `_set` como `_init`, ya que lo único que hace es invocar a `_set`

### De los comentarios

Si tienes que hacer varias solicitudes y coordinarlas, te recomiendo que aprendas Promesas (en inglés Promises). Aquí te dejo un enlace que trata de las diferencias entre callbacks y Promises:

[Diferencias entre AJAX anidadas y promises](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3582/diferencias-entre-ajax-anidadas-y-promises)

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta y los consejos me resultaron bastante logicos y me dieron un mejor entendimiento de mi problema. Lo que me gustaria saber es que sucederia si en la funcion _set tuviese a mas llamadas al servidor (es decir consuma no solo un servicio sino varios) todas ellas necesarias para inicializar variables que posteriormente utilizare en la funcion _create

Comment: @alexanderzevallos en ese caso, tendrás que hacer la segunda solicitud cuando termina la primera, o usar promises (lo cual te recomiendo aprendas) para coordinar todas las solicitudes. No hay forma de que puedas hacerlo como en lenguajes que se "bloquean" cuando lees un archivo o un recurso de la red. Debes siempre usar callbacks, es la ley de javascript.

Comment: @alexanderzevallos fijate que deje un link en la respuesta sobre promises.

Comment: Gracias por los consejos nuevamente @rnd ... hay demasiadas cosas que aun me faltan por aprender. Tomare en cuenta tu consejo acerca de promises.

Comment: @alexanderzevallos de nada! intentando se aprende! suerte!, por cierto no puedes marcar ambas respuestas como correctas, debes elejir una, es la ley de SO.. jaja.! suerte!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que es porque la función `_set` es asíncrona. Primero hace un pedido al servidor, y cuando vuelven los datos se ejecuta lo que hay adentro del `.success`. (Esta devolución desde estar tardando un poco y por eso se ejecuta el `_create` sin esperar la respuesta del `_set`)

En mi caso, uso dos formas para solucionar esto, invoco al `_create` adentro del `.success` o utilizo un callback.

Podés agregar el callback con algo como esto:

```
var template = {};
template = (function () {

var ROWS = -1;
var COLS = -1;

var _set = function (position, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: pathservicehost + '/posiciones/' + position,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            ROWS = data.TotalFila;
            COLS = data.TotalColumna;

            callback();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status) {
        }
    });

    if (PARAMETERS != null && ROWS > 0 && COLS > 0)
        _create(container);
};

var _create = function (container) {
    //Crea una tabla y lo coloca en 'container' usando las variables  globales ROWS y COLS
};

var _init = function (container, position) {
    _set(position, function(){
            _create(container);
        });

};

return {
    init: _init
}
})();
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @KN_ ... voy a gastar algunas horas leyendo más acerca de los callbacks.