# ¿ Como convierto una función que usa callbacks para que retorne una promesa?

Tags: javascript, promesas, refactoring, webix

Tengo una función, que usa `webix.ajax( )` para realizar llamadas AJAX.

En `webix`, AJAX tiene la *funcionalidad* de no gestionar los *timeout*; no los considera un error, sino que los trata como si la llamada hubiera sido exitosa.

Para remediarlo, creé esta función:

```
function timedAjax( timeout, callback, method, url, args ) {
  if( 'call' in timeout ) {
    args = url;
    url = method;
    method = callback;
    callback = timeout;
    timeout = 10000;
  }

  if( args )
    ( webix.ajax( ).timeout( timeout )[method] )( url, args, { success: ResponseOk, error: ResponseError } );
  else
    ( webix.ajax( ).timeout( timeout )[method] )( url, undefined, { success: ResponseOk, error: ResponseError } );

  function ResponseError( text, data, xhr ) {
    var err;

    setTimeout( function( ) { callback( xhr.status === 0 ? true : false, text, data, xhr ) }, 0 );
  }

  function ResponseOk( text, data, xhr ) {
    setTimeout( function( ) { callback( false, text, data, xhr ); }, 0 );
  }
}
```

El código funciona correctamente; si no se pasa un argumento `timeout`, establece un valor por defecto de `10000`ms, realiza la llamada a `webix.ajax( )` correspondiente, y llama a la función `callback` con los argumentos correctos:

- Si **no hay error**, la llama como

`callback( false, text, data, xhr )`

- Si **hay error**, incluyendo *timeout*, la llama como

`callback( true, text, data, xhr )`

Ahora, estoy intentando *modernizar* ese código. He encontrado mucha documentación sobre como usar las promesas, pero no termino de aclararme al respecto.

`webix` tiene compatiblidad con `Promises/A+`. La propia llamada a `webix.ajax( )` devuelve una *promise* con la funcionalidad indicada: si hay *timeout*, lo toma como reusultado exitoso.

¿ Como transformo el código anterior para que devuelva una *promise* ?

Comment: Sugiero que mires [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/64863/29967), en el apartado que dice **Uso básico de las Promesas**.

Comment: ¿La idea es que simplemente devuelva una [promise](https://docs.webix.com/api__ajax_post.html) (ver `Return value`) o que además devuelva los parámetros `error, text, data, xhr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es necesario que se continúe retornando los datos `error, text, data, xhr`, se me ocurre que podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Ya que vamos a devolver una `promise`, el parámetro `callback` habría que eliminarlo de la función `timedAjax`.
- Deberiamos crear una `promise` utilizando el metodo [`webix.promise.defer`](https://docs.webix.com/api__promise_defer.html)
- Luego dentro de las funciones `ResponseOk` y `ResponseError`, deberíamos resolver la `promise`.
  ***Nota**: El método `promise.resolve` solo aceptar un parametro, por lo que es necesario devolver un objeto con toda la info.*

Ejemplo:

```js
function timedAjax(timeout, method, url, args) {
  var promise = webix.promise.defer();
  
  if (isNaN(timeout)) {
    args = url;
    url = method;
    method = timeout;
    timeout = 10000;
  }
  
  webix.ajax().timeout(timeout)[method](url, args || undefined, {
    success: ResponseOk,
    error: ResponseError
  });
  
  return promise;
  
  //
  
  function ResponseError(text, data, xhr) {
    // NOTA: No rejectamos la promesa porque estamos enviando `error=true|false`
    promise.resolve({
      error: xhr.status === 0 ? true : false, 
      text: text,
      data: data, 
      xhr: xhr
    });
  }

  function ResponseOk( text, data, xhr ) {
    promise.resolve({
      error: false, 
      text: text,
      data: data, 
      xhr: xhr
    });
  }
}

//////////////////
// EJEMPLO DE USO

timedAjax(3000, 'get', '//www.google.com')
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.webix.com/edge/webix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Me has ahorrado responderte al comentario. Es **justo** lo que estaba buscando. Voy a probarlo.