# Disparar un evento luego de varios eventos.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Supongamos que tienes varias peticiones ajax y deseas disparar un evento solo cuando todas ellas se completen. ¿Existe algun modo elegante en JQuery de hacer esto?

Comment: Pues lo que se me ocurre es que las vayas anidando una dentro de la otra para que cuando llegue a la ultima dispare el evento que comentas, porque de otro modo si disparas todas y sin asincronas no todos terminan al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Hola Bienvenido a [es.SO], te invito a hacer el [tour] y también a que leas [ask], por otro lado tu pregunta puede considerarse de baja calidad o basada en opiniones, orientándote a lo que solicitas, revisa esta pregunta de promesas [¿Qué es una promesa en Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/64265/6635)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

si, lo que estas buscando es **Promesas**

**Qué son las promesas?**

> El objeto Promise (Promesa) es usado para computaciones asíncronas. Una promesa representa un valor que puede estar disponible ahora, en el futuro, o nunca.

Fuente: [¿Qué es una promesa en Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64265/qu%C3%A9-es-una-promesa-en-javascript/64403)

**Un llamado a ajax entonces no es una promesa?**

Claro, por eso podes hacer

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://algunsitio.com/datos.php",
})
.done(function( data ) {
  if ( console && console.log ) {
    console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
  }
});
```

.done se ejecuta recién cuando ajax devuelve los datos, entonces, para ejecutar lo que necesitas podes hacer

```
$.ajax(...)
 .done(function(data) {
  $.ajax(...)
  .done(..)
});
```

lo cual no es aconsejable, porque es poco legible.

**Al rescate, jquery when**

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

```
$.when(ajax1(), ajax2(), ajax3(), ajax4()).done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4){
    // el codigo aqui se ejecuta una vez que las cuatro promesas se 
    // resolvieron
});

function ajax1() {
    // NOTE:  esta funcion debe retornar el resultado 
    //        del metodo $.ajax(),el cual es una promesa.
    return $.ajax({
        url: "someUrl",
        dataType: "json",
        data:  yourJsonData,            
        ...
    });
}
```

( respuesta sacada de esta gran respuesta de otro usuario en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done )

**Alternativa:**

Otro método común en angular es usar la libreria Q y hacer Q.all

liberia Q: http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/

```
let promises = [promiseAlpha(), promiseBeta(), promiseGamma()];

$q.all(promises).then((values) => {
    console.log(values[0]); // value alpha
    console.log(values[1]); // value beta
    console.log(values[2]); // value gamma

    complete();
});
```

Pero leí por ahí que a veces Q.all no funciona correctamente.

También podrías volverte creativo y hacer que cada promesa ejecute un código y a su vez llene una variable

```
var promisesFulfilled = [0,0,0,0];

function promise0() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://algunsitio.com/datos.php",
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
      promisesFulfilled[0] = 1;
      checkPromises();
    });
}

function checkPromises() {
   //si promisesFulfilled tiene todos 1, ya se terminaron las 4.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

La solución más simple que se me ocurre es usar `Deferreds`

```
$.when(
    // Tambien funciona con get y post
    $.ajax("/primera"),
    $.ajax("/segunda"),
    $.ajax("/tercera")
    )
    .done(function(primero, segundo, tercero){
       // lo que quieras cuando funcione
    })
    .fail(function(){
        //lo que quieras cuando fallen
    });
```