# Como ejecutar una función después de unos segundos TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

Buen día, llevo unas horas buscando como hacer esto, pero sólo me sale para JavaScript, se puede con `setTimeout("función()", tiempo);` pero pues igualmente no me sirve para TypeScript.

Mi código en TypeScript.

```
  if (element.email == mail && element.pass == passw) {
    this.loginAutentication = true;
    Swal.fire({
      type: 'success',
      text: 'Welcome ' + element.rol + '.',
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 1500
    });
    setTimeout("goToDashboard()", 1500); //Quiero que aquí se ejecute la función a los mismos segundos que acaba el PopUp de arriba.
  }
```

Error que me sale luego de que termina el PopUp y se ejecuta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ante mano muchas gracias por colaborarme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para sincronizar el código no es necesario hacer el setTimeout justo en el mismo momento que swal, para ello puedes utilizar las promesas que devuelve la propia libreria

https://sweetalert2.github.io/#handling-dismissals

Podrías hacerlo de esta manera:

```
if (element.email == mail && element.pass == passw) {
    this.loginAutentication = true;
    Swal.fire({
      type: 'success',
      text: 'Welcome ' + element.rol + '.',
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 1500
    })
    .then((result) => {
        this.goToDashboard();
    });
  }
```

De todas maneras si quieres seguir utilizando el setTimeout por algún motivo, te recomiendo que pases una función como primer argumento a setTimeout, en lugar de una cadena.

```
setTimeout(() => {
 this.goToDashboard()
}, 1500);
```

Si la función "goToDashboard" no esta definida en el momento de la ejecución, deberías enunciar mejor tu problema y poner el código para poder ver mejor que ocurre.

Comment: De tú solución sólo me funcionó el primero, pero pues como es TypeScript para llamar a la función tienes que colocarle "this" para que quede así.
`    .then((result) => {
        this.goToDashboard();
    });`

Comment: Edito la respuesta, entonces, el "this" que indicas en typescript tiene un valor distinto dependiendo del contexto.

Comment: Exacto, pero en cuanto a funciones me enseñaron que tiene que ser así, y sí, edítala por si a alguien también le pasa, igual ahí ya tienes la respuesta de la pregunta, te daré un punto positivo.

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme. :)

Comment: No es por Typescript, es Javascript en general: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130068/contexto-this-en-un-objeto