# Convertir método de ASINCRONO a SINCRONO con Promises

Tags: javascript, promesas

Tengo un método ASINCRONO en JS llamado `gnClienteFirma.Firmar(textoAFirmar)`. Dicho método tiene dos callbacks una vez ejecutado:

```
function FirmaResultCallBack(signature) {...} //Si se firma OK.

function FirmaErrorFunction(errorType, errorMessage) {...} Si firma da algún error.
```

¿Cómo puedo convertir dicho método de ASINCRONO a SINCRONO?

He probado con 'promises' pero no acierto a verlo:

```
function FirmarPromise(textoAFirmar) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            gnClienteFirma.Firmar(textoAFirmar, function FirmaResultCallBack(signature) {
                resolve(signature);
            }, function FirmaErrorFunction(errorType, errorMessage) {
                return reject(errorMessage);  
            });
        })
    }
```

Comment: Una promesa sigue siendo algo asíncrono, simplemente es más elegante.

Comment: cuando hablas de sincrono y promesas es contradictorio,

Answer (score 3):

otra forma de esperar un valor (igual sigue siendo asincrono) es con async/await, pero esto suele dar mas problemas por compatibilidad

```js
function firmarPromesa(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('chispas!!');
    }, 2000);
  });
}
async function esperareUnValor(){
  console.log('ejecuta funcion');
  let chispas = await firmarPromesa();
  console.log(chispas);


}

esperareUnValor()
```

pero si usas promesas , te dejo un ejemplo

```js
function promesa1(){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        //mi codigo a Validar
           setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('chispas!!');
          }, 2000);
    })
}
function promesa2(message){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        //mi codigo a Validar
        reject("error en la promesa 2 pero recibio " + message )
    })
}
promesa1().
  then(function(message){
    console.log("ejecutando promesa 1")
    return promesa2(message)
  
}).then(function(message){
  console.log("aqui no llegara")
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log("error" ,err)
})
```

> Te recomiendo leer [Que es una Promesa en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64265/qu%C3%A9-es-una-promesa-en-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Una promesa es una forma de encapsular un código asíncrono para hacerlo más manejable, pero no dejará de ser asíncrono. En cualquier caso, si tienes una función así:

```
function firma(datos,exitoFn,falloFn) {...}
```

puedes hacer algo como:

```
let firmaPromesa=new Promise(function (exito,fallo) {
  firma(datos,exito,fallo);
}

firmaPromesa.then(function (signature) {...})
  .catch(function(errorType, errorMessage) {...});
```