# ¿Cómo podría sacar el valor de dentro de una función que está dentro de otra?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Me gustaría poder sacar el valor de dentro del fetch:

```
getFeaturedMedia = json => {
   var result = null;

   fetch(json)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
         result = responseJson.source_url; // I want to get this value out of here, with a return
      console.log("Inside: " + result);
   })
   .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
   });

   return result;
};
```

Comment: agrega donde llamas a getFeaturedMedia

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Convertir método de ASINCRONO a SINCRONO con Promises](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/149069/convertir-m%c3%a9todo-de-asincrono-a-sincrono-con-promises)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función fetch retorna una [promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise), para poder efectuarlo asincronamente es nesario usar await y async [Funcion asincronamente](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona)

```
const getFeaturedMedia = async (json) => {
  let result = null;

  try {
    result = await fetch(json);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  if(result.ok) {
     return result.json();
  }

  // muestra el error retornado por la petición
  console.log(result.statusText);
};
```

La función al ser async retorna una promesa de un objeto plano, siendo necesario efectuar un `await` a la llamada de la función:

```
const media = await getFeaturedMedia('http://...');
```

Ó un `then()` y tratar la respuesta dentro del then:

```
let media;
getFeaturedMedia('...').then((response) => { media = response; });
```

Comment: Lo he probado y solo obtengo un [object Object] del return.

Comment: Lo he editado y me salía el object. Luego lo he copiado y pegado, comprobado que el json funcione corréctamente... nada, me devuelve [object Object]

Comment: Ahora me devuelve esto:
Promise {
    "_40": 0,
    "_55": null,
    "_65": 0,
    "_72": null,
}

Comment: He probado a devolver el valor con el JSON.stringfy y me devuelve exactamente lo mismo

Comment: He acabado comprendiendo el funcionamiento de las promesas... que no se pueden sacar localmente del "then". Ergo, he usado el state de react native con un vector para ir actualizando las variables a medida que iba sacando los json del then, porque no he encontrado otra forma de usar el valor de dentro del "then" que no sea la de actualizar el state... Gracias igualmente @osiris85

Comment: @PedroManuelCrespoJiménez al llamar la funcion intenta algo como : `await getFeaturedMedia() `

Comment: tal y como indica @JackNavaRow y como indiqué en el comentario anterior al retornar una Promise de objeto plano hay que hacer await o then. He modificado la respuesta

Comment: @osiris85 elimina los comentarios que crees que no son necesarios