# Llamada asíncrona a servicio REST con Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promesas, asincronismo, async

Tengo una lista llamada 'aseguradoras':

`var aseguradoras = [aseguradora1,aseguradora2,aseguradora3];`

Quiero hacer una llamada a un servicio con cada aseguradora, en este caso 3 llamadas. El problema es que tengo que hacer las llamadas asíncronas, para ir añadiendo el objeto que me devuelva en un array según la llamada que termine antes.

```
            for(var i=0; i<aseguradoras.length; i++){
                datos.ASEGURADORA = aseguradoras[i];
                PresupuestoService.getTarificacionByAseguradora(datos).then(
                    function successCallback(response){
                        vm.tarifas.push(response.data.TARIFAS);
                    },
                    function(error){
                        console.log('Unsuccesful');
                    }
                );
            }
```

Llamada a servicio REST:

```
function PresupuestoService($http, $rootScope, BASE_CON) {

        var token = _.get($rootScope, 'globals.currentUser.token');
        token = token || '';

        var service = {};

        service.getTarificacionByAseguradora = getTarificacionByAseguradora;

        function getTarificacionByAseguradora(json){
            var url=BASE_CON+"/Presupuestos/getTarificacionByAseguradora";
            return get(url,token,json);
        }

        //Get
        function get(url, token, json){
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: json,
                headers: {'Authorization':'Token ' + token , 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}    //Permiso para la petición.
            });
        }
    };
```

Anteriormente, recorria las aseguradoras en un bucle y hacia la llamada, pero eso no me sirve, porque hasta que no acabe esa llamada no empieza la siguiente, y eso es lo que quiero, que se hagan todas a la vez y lo que devuelva meterlo en un array.Espero que me podais ayudar, me he informado mucho sobre la asincronia en javascript y no me queda muy claro...

Comment: El bucle, tal y como lo tienes puesto en la pregunta, ya hace todas las llamadas a la vez, sin esperar la respuesta.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Convertir método de ASINCRONO a SINCRONO con Promises](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/149069/convertir-m%c3%a9todo-de-asincrono-a-sincrono-con-promises)

Comment: esto te puede ayudar [async y await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: algo estas haciendo que no nos estás mostrando, las llamadas vienen por defecto asíncronas, entonces, a menos que tu lo hayas cambiado a propósito, ese código debería funcionar. Como estas haciendo las llamadas a servidor? podrías mostrar código de la petición?

Comment: @LPZadkiel Si, ya está editada la respuesta.

Comment: No es por ser quisquilloso, pero tener un método que se llama `get` y que hace un `POST` es una pésima idea

Comment: @PabloLozano Tienes razón.

Comment: lo que estas usando es `angularjs` con `promises` , creo que si cambias las etiquetas vas a llegar a más gente que te pueda ayudar

Answer (score 2):

Como dice @PabloLozano las llamadas se hacen sin esperar la respuesta.

**Edito**. Pongo un ejemplo para que veas que tal y como lo tienes no está esperando a que finalice la llamada de todas las `promises`.

```js
let aseguradoras = ["aseg1","aseg2","aseg3"];
let aseguradorasTimeout = [5000,1000,2500];
let llamadasFinalizadas = [];
for(var i=0; i<aseguradoras.length; i++){
  later(aseguradorasTimeout[i],aseguradoras[i]).then(
    function successCallback(response){
      llamadasFinalizadas.push(response);
      console.log(llamadasFinalizadas);
    },
    function(error){
      console.log('Unsuccesful');
    }
  );
}

function later(delay,name) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        resolve("Soy " + name + " y he terminado en " + delay + " ms.");
      }, delay);
    });
}
```

Comment: No, eso es más o menos lo que me hace el bucle. Si supuestamente esas 3 llamadas se están haciendo a la vez, necesito que según acabe una llamada, añada lo que recibe en la lista de tarifas y no tenga que esperar a que acaben todas para añadirlo a la lista.

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta con un ejemplo. Tal y como lo tienes no está esperando a que termine una para añadir al array. Las promises se van lanzando y se van completando asíncronamente.

Comment: He editado el código de arriba a como más o menos me has dicho tú.  Cuando recorre el bucle 1, 2, 3 o las veces que sean, no me hace la llamada hasta que lo recorra entero, entonces ahí es cuando me hace las 5 (por ejemplo) llamadas a la vez y con la misma aseguradora.. No hace las llamadas con todas las aseguradoras, si no con la última de la lista.

Comment: Puedes poner el código de `PresupuestoService.getTarificacionByAseguradora`?

Comment: ya está puesto.