# Diferencia entre then, observable y subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, promesas, observable, rxjs

he visto algunos códigos donde se usan las funciones de `then`, `observable`, y `subscribe`. No estoy seguro pero creo que todas resultan haciendo lo mismo, quisiera saber con un ejemplo si es posible cual es la diferencia entre ellas o cuando utilizar cada una. Muchas gracias

Comment: creo que para eso esta la documentación y mucha información extra

Comment: Hola @TheVicious , si la documentación se encuentra solo en idioma ingles sería buena idea agregar una respuesta en español, saludos.

Comment: agrega ejemplos con cada uno de los metodos

Comment: @JackNavaRow no es pereza mia, sino que en este preciso momento no recuerdo en que codigos lo vi, por eso me gustaria si alguien tiene una manera más coherente y fácil de hacer entender esto, a fin de que todos podamos entender y tengamos clara la diferencia. además si busco ejemplos en codigos diferentes creo que tal vez alguien podria hacer algo más consistente para este caso

Comment: @TheVicious es cierto, la documentación esta en inglés, y este portal esta en español, esto también para los usuarios de la comunidad que puedan aprender más facilmente y nos quede ese aprendizaje, mi inglés es malo y no me queda muy claro lo que hace cada uno y en cuales casos usarlos

Comment: Aquí os dejo un vídeo de una charla en español donde explican la reactividad y el subscribe desde cero: [T3chFest2018 - Entendiendo la Reactividad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzkUJifOZdM&t=1964s)

Answer (score 15):

Voy a intentar explicar los 3 conceptos:

### Observable

Es una interfaz, prácticamente es la base de la [programación reactiva](https://profile.es/blog/que-es-la-programacion-reactiva-una-introduccion/). Puesto que [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) hace un uso intenso de esta metodología, conviene conocer la librería [RxJS](https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs).

Los objetos que implementan esta interfaz, son objetos que podemos *observar* (qué sorpresa, ¿verdad?).

¿Qué significa esto? Que te puedes subscribir a ellos y cada vez que ocurra *algo*, te lo harán saber.

Pongo un ejemplo:

```js
//Nota: esta no es la forma óptima de importar la librería!
//las limitaciones de los fragmentos de SOes obligan a esto

//no funciona aquí, pero usando Webpack/Node, lo ideal sería algo como
//import { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range,fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
//import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const { Observable, Subject, ReplaySubject, from, of, range,fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { map, filter, switchMap } = rxjs.operators;

let boton=document.getElementById('boton');
var clickObservable = fromEvent(boton, 'click');

let suscripcion = clickObservable.subscribe(()=> console.log('Clickado'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<button id="boton">click</button>
```

Nos hemos suscrito a un evento click en el botón: cada vez que ocurra algo se ejecutará la función que le hemos pasado en el método **subscribe**.

### Observables en Angular (AJAX, principalmente)

Cuando usamos Angular, hacemos uso de Observables para hacer peticiones AJAX, de la siguiente manera:

```
class Servicio {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getRecurso(id :string) : Observable<Recurso>{
    return this.http.get<Recurso>(MI_URL + id);
  }
}
```

Aquí he definido un servicio que nos obtiene *recursos* por una id, devolviendo un Observable que provee recursos.

En nuestro componente, usaremos este servicio de la siguiente manera:

```
class Componente {

  private recurso: Recurso = null;

  constructor(private miServicio: Servicio) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.miServicio.getRecurso('un_identificador').subscribe(
      (re: Recurso) => {
        this.recurso=re;
      },
      (error) => {
        this.trataError(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

No usamos `then` porque ese método **no** está disponible, no existe en la clase observable. Su equivalente (o casi) es **subscribe**.

No quiero explicar toda la API de RxJS aquí, pero además de `subscribe` hay multitud de métodos aplicables a un `Observable` que pueden ser útiles: `map`, `catch`, `from`, `of`, `toPromise` (este puede ser interesante para los que no quieren usar más que promesas, pero desaprovecha mucho la potencia de los Observables) y muchos más.

### .then

¡Este método no tiene nada que ver con Observables! Es un método de una clase que representa otro concepto: las promesas. De la clase `Promise` no explicaré nada porque **gugadev** ya lo dejó todo clarito en [esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64265/qu%C3%A9-es-una-promesa-en-javascript).

Sólo déjame enfatizar que

- si usamos `Promise`, usaremos `.then(...)`.
- si usamos `Observable` usaremos `.subscribe(...)`.

Comment: Pabo muchas gracias por tu tiempo, entiendo, pero no me queda muy claro en un ejemplo como este `this.http.post(url,data).subscribe`  no entiendo que hace aqui el subscribe especificamente, porque segun entiendo también podria poner un ´.then´ gracias.

Comment: Te he puesto otro ejemplo, a ver si ayuda