# console.log con valores y return undefined

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

```
var got = require('got')
exports.coger = function (id){
let i;
if (!id){
    i = "Introduzca una id";
    return i;
}
got(`enlace privado`).then(f => {
    let a = JSON.parse(f.body)
    console.log(a)
    if(a.error){
       i = a.error
        return i;
    }
    i ={"usuario":a.usuario,"id":a.id,"descripcion":a.descripcion,"fecha":a.fecha,"multicuentas":a.multicuentas}
    return i;
})

}
```

tambien he probado a poner el `return i`; fuera del }) pero sigue dando `undefined` todo funciona bien menos el final ya que al hacer `return i`; me dice `undefined` en vez del objeto i

Comment: eso pasa porque el proceso es asincrono te invito a leer [Que es una promesa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64265/qu%C3%A9-es-una-promesa-en-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Cuando no le pasas un `id` la función  `coger` te entrega un resultado inmediado. En otro caso, llama a una función que devuelve una promesa y hasta que esa promesa no se resuelve, `i` sigue siendo indefinido.

Debieras manejarlo devolviendo siempre una promesa:

```
var got = require('got')
exports.coger = function (id) {

    let i;
    if (!id) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error("Introduzca una id"));
    }
    return got(`/enlace/${id}`).then(f => {
        let a = JSON.parse(f.body)
        console.log(a)
        if (a.error) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error(a.error));
        }
        i = {
            "usuario": a.usuario,
            "id": a.id,
            "descripcion": a.descripcion,
            "fecha": a.fecha,
            "multicuentas": a.multicuentas
        }
        return i;
    });

}
```

Y luego llamar a `coger` manejando su resultado con `then/catch`

```
coger(id).then((res)=>{
    console.log('Resultado: ', res);
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log('Error: ',err);
});
```

Por lo que veo en tu código, puede darse el caso en que un request tenga éxito pero la respuesta contenga un mensaje de error, por eso incluí un error explícito que será interceptado por tu `catch` en esa circunstancia. Otros errores en el request mismo igual irán a parar al catch pero con un mensaje distinto.

Comment: en la linea `return i;` , no debes retornar un new Promise con resolve(i)?

Comment: Podría envolverlo haciendo `return Promise.resolve(i)` pero creo que es redundante. Lo que se retorna dentro de una promesa eventualmente será el valor con que se resuelva el llamado original.  Incluso creo que usar `Promise.reject` es redundante porque podría simplemente hacer un `throw` dentro del `then` de `got`.

Comment: @JackNavaRow una prueba aquí: https://runkit.com/embed/21em990atx8e