# ¿Como utilizar async await en una respuesta de firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, async

Buen día.

Actualmente estoy obteniendo una respuesta de firebase, a la cual estoy intentando utilizar async y await, soy nuevo en este tema de asyn/await.

```
 parqueo = await firebase.database().ref("parqueos").child(historial[i].zona_parqueo).child(historial[i].codigo_parqueo).once('value');
    console.log("PARQUEO");
    console.log(parqueo.val());
```

Pero en la consola me sale el siguiente error: **await is a reserved word**
En donde debería utilizar la palabra async.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Duda sobre Promises y async await?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/205362/duda-sobre-promises-y-async-await)

Comment: ¿como aplicarlo a firebase?

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías agregar el contexto en el que usas las ***3*** líneas de código que publicaste? Saludos.