# JavaScript. Como hago una función asincrona que solamente se encargue de llamar a la API?

Tags: javascript, function, async

Necesito hacer una función asíncrona que solamente sea la encargada de llamar a la API.
De ésta función necesito tomar los valores para usar en otra parte del código. Lo grafíco para que lo entiendan:

Esta es mi funcion:

```
async function live() {

    const res = await fetch(`https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures/live`, {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": `mi key`
        }
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    let liveMatches = data.api;
}
```

Si yo paso como parámetro `liveMatches` asi: `async function live(liveMatches)` y despues hago `console.log(live(liveMatches))` me devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, la Promise indefinida.

Entonces en principio necesito que me devuelva la respuesta de la api.

Una vez tenga la respuesta de la API, puedo usar la variable `liveMatches` en otra parte del código **fuera de esa funcion?**
Llamando la función con el parámetro?
es decir, hacer algo como esto es válido?:

```
function test(){
   live(liveMatches);
   console.log(live(liveMatches));
}
```

O tendría que a `test()` pasarle como parámetro `live(liveMatches))` ?

Comment: hay un problema con tu criterio: realizar algo asyncrono y luego utilizar la data en otra parte: entonces necesitas usar promise.

Comment: Como deberia hacer?

Comment: ya agregue una respuesta.

Comment: Ahora pruebo si me funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero debes entender cómo funcionan las Promesas. Una vez entiendes el concepto, verás que `async/ await`no es más que azúcar sintáctico.
Te recomiendo ver esta [pregunta y sus respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/205362/duda-sobre-promises-y-async-await).

Si quieres ver otro ejemplo, aquí tienes [otra pregunta/respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243352/secuencia-de-retornos-incorrecta-usando-async-await) que considero interesante, porque se ve el equivalente entre promesas y async/await

Entonces, lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
async function live() {
    const res = await fetch(`https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures/live`, {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": `mi key`
        }
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    return data.api;
}

let liveMatches = live(); //tienes una promesa
liveMatches.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando Promise, deberías poder tener la escalabilidad que indicas, debes adaptarla a tu necesidad:

```
var AsyncData;
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  /* Codigo ajax Asincrono */
  /* Guardar en AsyncData */
  setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000);
});

promise.then(function(result) {
  /* Manipular AsyncData */
  alert(result); // 1
  return result * 2;
});
```

[Documentación #1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

[Documentación #2](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)