# Devolucion de valor return en node js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, google-maps

Tengo una duda. Estoy haciendo una petición a la API de Google Maps, pero el detalle es que no me retorna el valor de `result` cuando ejecuto el programa; quizás esté haciendo algo mal, soy nuevo en Node.js y también en programación.

```
'use strict'
const request = require("request");

function geocoding(lat,long){   
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+long+"&key=aqui va la key"

    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received  

      var result = JSON.parse(body);
      return result;
  });
};

geocoding(-15.850519, -70.026469);
```

Comment: Ya estas regresando un resultado, ahora `geocoding(-15.850519, -70.026469);` tiene dentro encapsulada la respuesta, es decir, la tienes pero no estas haciendo nada con ella. Puedes ver tu resultado con `console.log( geocoding(-15.850519, -70.026469) ) ;` o en todo caso enviarla al front por express o cualquier framework que estes usando

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob estoy haciendo un console.log como me dices pero me muestra el valor de undefined, o algo estoy haciendo mal en el codigo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fíjate bien en el código. La función `geocoding` **no retorna nada**, la función que retorna `result` es el *callback* de la petición que estás realizando.

> **No debes retornar desde un callback**. No podrás capturar ese valor debido a que la función en sí es un parámetro.

Lo que retornas en un callback se pierde en memoria. Tienes dos opciones:

---

[**Usar un callback**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

Esta es la forma clásica. Agrega un tercer parámetro a la función `geocoding` que será una función (callback) que será ejecutado en cuanto la petición (`request`) se resuelva, pasándole por parámetro `result`:

```
function geocoding(lat,long, cb){   // nuevo parámetro
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+long+"&key=aqui va la key"

    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('error:', error);
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);

      var result = JSON.parse(body);
      cb(error, result); // se lo pasas al callback
  });
};

geoconding(x, y, (err, result) => {
  // hacer algo con err y result
})
```

---

[**Retornar una promesa**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise)

Esta es la forma "moderna". Consiste en retornar una promesa cuyo valor a resolver puede estar dentro de un callback (incluso en callbacks anidados).

```
function geocoding(lat,long){   
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+long+"&key=aqui va la key"

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error);
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);

        if (error) { reject(error) }
        else { resolve(JSON.parse(body)) }
      });
    })
};

geoconding(x, y)
  .then(result => {
    // hacer algo con result
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // manejar el error
  })
```

Comment: PD: Investiga sobre ES2015 y sus novedades. Ya no es necesario usar `var` ni concatenar strings. Usa JavaScript moderno ;)

Comment: ¿Puedes explicarte un poco más? ¿Te refieres a confundirse por los nombres o cuando se está depurando? Si es lo primero, hay que ser consciente que los nombres no son importantes, si no el orden de las funciones. En lo segundo no tendrá impacto porque es son funciones anónimas.

Comment: Hecho, aunque no estoy de acuerdo. Cuando miren un código en Github o algún lado que no tenga esos nombres, probablemente tengan problemas para interpretarlo, cosa que no debería pasar bajo ningún concepto. Entender el funcionamiento y la implementación es lo importante.

Comment: Soy nuevo en javascript y por ende en node js Logre entender el segundo metodo que es retornando con una promesa, creo que es un poco mas entendible, estoy tratando de guardar el resultado en una variable en una variable, pero la llamada de funcion a geocoding se puede almacenar en una variable?

Comment: @Nik si retornas una promesa, lo que obtendrás como retorno es esa. `const geoResults = geocoding(x, y)`.

Comment: una pregunta, que significa "Promise { <pending> }" al ejecutar?? me sale ese mensaje

Comment: algo asi?? const resultGeo = reverseGeocoding(-15.850519, -70.026469)

.then(result => {
  console.log(result)
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})

console.log(resultGeo); ??

Comment: @Nik Te invito a leer la siguiente [pregunta y su explicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64265/qu%c3%a9-es-una-promesa-en-javascript/64403#64403).

Comment: En si tengo que recibir 2 parametros "lat,long" mediante la funcion geocoding a la api de google maps que me genera coordenadas, luego tengo que retornar el JSON que me devuelve la funcion geocoding y almacenar en una variable origen o destino para despues interactuar con los valores que almaceno en las variables origen o destino, algo asi: let origen = geocoding(lat,long)
console.log(origen)

Comment: @Nik ¿Leíste el enlace que te acabo de proporcionar?

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo utilizar async await en estos casos, si quisieras hacer eso. Además el use strict no es necesario en este caso :)

```
`const request = require("request");

async function geocoding(lat,long){   
   const url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";

   try{
      const {body} = await request(url);

  if(!body){
   //manejar caso de body empty
   }

 return JSON.parse(body);
}catch(err){
 //manejar error
}
};

geocoding(-15.850519, -70.026469);`
```

Comment: podrías explicar qué hace ese código? ayudaría a que la respuesta se entienda más para los demás usuarios de la comunidad