# Una Funcion AJAX, me detiene un setInterval de otra funcion

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Cordial Saludo,

Les comento, tengo un formulario que envía un archivo `excel` con `ajax` a `php` y lo inserta en una `bd` y hace otros procesos, eso está perfecto.

Pero también tengo otra función que consulta en la `bd` lo que se ha insertado con un *setinterval*.

El problema es que al momento de ejecutar la función que tiene que enviar el `excel` e insertar en la `bd`, las funciones de mi página con *setinterval* se detienen hasta que ese proceso se complete, y necesito que no se detengan:

Función para enviar el **form**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){
            $("#Excel").on("submit", function(e){

              e.preventDefault();
              var f = $(this);
              var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("Excel"));

                $.ajax({
                  url: "PHP/Consultar_Cantidad_Excel.php",
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "html",
                  data: formData,
                  cache: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false
                })
                .done(function(res){

                    Cargar_Barra();
                    //alert(res);
                    var partes = res.split('*');
                    CODE_EXCEL = partes[0]; 
                    CANTIDAD_REGISTROS = partes[1];
                    RUTA_EXCEL = partes[2];

                    //alert(RUTA_EXCEL);

                    $("#REGISTROS_EXCEL").html(CANTIDAD_REGISTROS);
                    $("#CANTIDAD_REGISTROS_EXCEL_INPUT").val(CANTIDAD_REGISTROS);
                    $("#CODIGO_EXCEL_CONSULTA").val(CODE_EXCEL);

                    datos = {'CODE_EXCEL':CODE_EXCEL,'target_path':RUTA_EXCEL};

                        $.ajax({
                        url: 'PHP/Cargar_Fidelizacion_Masiva.php',
                        data: datos,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(Insert){

                            //alert(Insert);
                            Cargar_Barra();      
                        }

                        });


                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Función *setinterval* que se detiene:

```
function Cargar_Barra(){

        CANT_EXCEL = $("#CANTIDAD_REGISTROS_EXCEL_INPUT").val();
        CODE_EXCEL = $("#CODIGO_EXCEL_CONSULTA").val();

        datos = {'CANT_EXCEL':CANT_EXCEL,'CODE_EXCEL':CODE_EXCEL};

        $.ajax({
        url: 'PHP/Consultar_Barra_Progreso.php',
        data: datos,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(Op){

            console.log(Op);

            $('.progress-bar').css('width', Op+'%');
            $('.progress-bar').attr('aria-valuenow', Op);
            $('.progress-bar').text(Op+'%');

            //complete
            if (Op == 100) {
                clearInterval(timerId);
                $('.information').show();
            }


        }

        });

}

timerId = setInterval(Cargar_Barra, 100);
```

Espero me entiendan y me puedan ayudar,

Cabe destacar que la función que envía el `excel`, tarda algo en procesarse todo y obtener la respuesta

Comment: Es cuestion de las peticiones que haces , la peticion a 'PHP/Consultar_Barra_Progreso.php', puede tardar mas o menos que la que haces a 'PHP/Cargar_Fidelizacion_Masiva.php'. Quizas tengas que concatenar de otra manera las peticiones. Si miras las pestaña network de las herramientras del desarrolador podras ver el orden en que haces la peticiones y el tiempo que tardan

Comment: Si, porque la que envía el form se va a demorar algo, pero necesito que las otras sigan funcionando, ¿Que se puede hacer en este caso?
Gracias

Comment: Cuando quieres parar el intervalo ?

Comment: Quizás esto te de ideas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/2802/822

Comment: dejame ver si te entendido bien...  quieres que tu codigo se siga ejecutando pero `timerId` es `global` se llama a la funcion nuevamente despues de que `termine la peticion` y se vuelve a llamar otra vez cuando `termina la peticion` apuntando a la misma clase  `class='progress-bar'`, pero no quieres que se pause? creo que esto te puede ayudar: como funcionan los [callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

Comment: Lo que pasa es, ambas funcionan bien. pero cuando ejecuto una, la del boton, todas las funciones en mi pagina que usan el setinterval, se detienen, hasta que ese proceso terminé, y yo no quiero que eso pasé

Comment: Ya lo logré solucionar, fue un tema de sessiones en PHP, y puse las funciones async y ya funcion lo que hacia, quedó perfecto, gracias